# Why no implicit output argument after caught import error when using python from matlab?

Tags: python, matlab

Following [this example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-user-defined-custom-module.html), but modified as follows:

```
try:
    import h5py
except ImportError as e:
    print e

"""Python module demonstrates passing MATLAB types to Python functions"""
def search(words):
    """Return list of words containing 'son'"""
    newlist = [w for w in words if 'son' in w]
    return newlist
```

why does `py.list` seem to not return an implicit output argument the first time it's called?

```
>> py.mymod.search(py.list({'Jones','Johnson','James'}))
cannot import name _errors
Python Error: search() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)

>> py.mymod.search(py.list({'Jones','Johnson','James'}))

ans = 

  Python list with no properties.

    ['Johnson']
```